# Extract text of paragraph using nextSibling

Tags: javascript

How can I extract a text of paragraph using `nextSibling` on this paragraph? I tried many variants, e.g. `nextSibling.nodeValue` or `nextSibling.textContent` but none of them work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("p1");
        var b = a.nextSibling.nodeValue;
        console.log(b);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="p1">
      Some text
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the Sibling of p1?

Comment: `a.nodeValue`,,

Comment: p1 has no siblings?

Comment: The `nextSibling` of `a` is the text node between `</p>` and `</body>`. There is no paragraph to extract the text from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text nodes in JavaScript are children of their DOM tag. So, instead of sibling, use a child selector: `a.firstChild` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add a sibbling in your html code. Add another paragraph after p1 if you want nextSibbling to return something. 
If you just want the text of p1 you don't need to use nextSibbling. `a.textContent` should be enough.